# test-framework/quickcheck/cabal: Passing options to testfunction with 'cabal test'

Tags: testing, haskell, cabal, quickcheck

I'm using cabal to build and test my projects with the commands:

```
cabal configure --enable-tests
cabal build
cabal test
```

As a framework I use testing-framework (https://batterseapower.github.io/test-framework/).
Everything works, however the number of QuickCheck-tests defaults to 50 which in my use-case is very little because I have to filter the generated data to fit certain properties.

Is there any possibility to pass something like

```
--maximum-generated-tests=5000
```

to the test-executable via cabal? I tried things like

```
 cabal test --test-options='maximum-generated-tests=5000'
```

but no luck so far. Is there any possibility to achieve this?

Many thanks in advance!

jules

Comment: Didn't anyone tell you, Haskell doesn't need unit testing :)  (I am only half joking :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the dashes:

```
cabal test --test-options=--maximum-generated-tests=5000
```

Also, if too few generated tests satisfy your property, you may have better luck with [SmallCheck](https://github.com/feuerbach/smallcheck). It's not random and thus will find *all* inputs satisfying the condition in the given search space. (Disclosure: I'm the maintainer of SmallCheck.)

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try out the tasty/SmallCheck combination